# Android Alert Dialog causing crash on .show()

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

So my app has a timer that displays in the main activity as it is counting down. I want an alarm to play when the timer is done, so I schedule an intent that sounds the alarm using AlarmManager and a class to extend BroadcastReceiver.

Everything works fine until the alarm goes off. I traced the crash to the line where I call show() on my AlertDialog. I feel like it has something to do with the application context and the code not being in MainActivity or something, but I can't seem to find anything with a similar configuration and the same crash source.

Here is the alert dialog code

```
public class SoundAlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ...///Play sound code is here and works

            final CharSequence [] options = {"OK"};
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Title");
            builder.setMessage("Beer is done!");
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if(which == 0) {
                        mp.stop();
                        mp.release();
                    }
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
... //other stuff
```

Here is the code that schedules with the AlarmManager which is found in MainActivity.java:

```
//Schedule the alarm
    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundAlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar fireTime = Calendar.getInstance();
    fireTime.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    fireTime.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, time);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, fireTime.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Also, as an aside, changing the MainActivity.this to getApplicationContext() for the pending intent does not fix the crash. Saw a lot of people suggesting using one or the other, but my crash persists no matter which one I use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I feel like it has something to do with the application context and the code not being in MainActivity or something,

Yes, you need an `Activity` to show a `Dialog`.

What you can do is build a separate `Activity` with the `layout` you want and start it from the `Receiver`. You can add the following code to the `<activity>` tag of your `manifest.xml` to make it appear as a `Dialog`.

```
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
```

[From the Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html)

> Note: Activities provide a facility to manage the creation, saving and restoring of dialogs.

Comment: Is there no way that I can show a dialog from my receiver class?

Comment: Ah well...ended up using NotificationManager and got the functionality I was looking for. Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad you were able to get what you needed.